# Play: How to validate a list of emails in JSON

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Given the following JSON...

```
{
  "recipients" : [
    "user1@domain1.com", "user2@domain2.com"
  ],
  "subject" : "My subject",
  "body" : "My body"
}
```

... I need to validate the recipient list... and here below is my code:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._

val js = Json.parse("""{"subject":"My subject","body":"My body", "recipients":["user1@domain1.com","user2@domain2.com"]}""")

val validateRecipients = verifyingIf((arr: JsArray) =>
  arr.value.nonEmpty)(Reads.email)
val recipients: Reads[JsArray] = {
  (__ \ 'recipients).json.pick[JsArray] andThen validateRecipients
} 

val validateNotification = (
  ((__ \ 'recipients).json.copyFrom(recipients)) ~
  ((__ \ 'subject).json.pickBranch) ~
  ((__ \ 'body).json.pickBranch)
).reduce 

validateNotification.reads(js).fold(
  valid = { validated => JsSuccess(validated) },
  invalid = { errors => JsError(errors) }
)
```

The problem is that my validator doesn't work:

```
res1: Product with Serializable with play.api.libs.json.JsResult[play.api.libs.json.JsObject] = JsError(List((/recipients,List(ValidationError(error.expected.jsstring,WrappedArray())))))
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code like this:

```
val validateRecipients = verifyingIf((arr: JsArray) =>   arr.value.nonEmpty)(Reads.list(Reads.email))
```